Grouped bar chart using plotly crosstalk
I am using crosstalk to implement a filter to a chart on a quarto dashboard. The graph is a grouped bar chart, showing two values per group. The filter then changes the indicator being observed. The functionality works okay in the sense it is returning the correct value bars when the filter is applied. The issue revolves around the fact the bars within the group are spaced out, in the positions they would be if all the indicators and their values by group were shown at the same instance.
See code below to replicate problem:
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(crosstalk)
library(htmltools)

df <- data.frame(FirstSecond = c("First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second",
                                "First", "Second"),
                Group = c("Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1",
                          "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1",
                          "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2",
                          "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2",
                          "Group 3", "Group 3", "Group 3", "Group 3",
                          "Group 3", "Group 3", "Group 3", "Group 3"),
              Indicator = c("Indicator 1","Indicator 1","Indicator 2","Indicator 2",
                            "Indicator 3","Indicator 3","Indicator 4","Indicator 4",
                            "Indicator 1","Indicator 1","Indicator 2","Indicator 2",
                            "Indicator 3","Indicator 3","Indicator 4","Indicator 4",
                            "Indicator 1","Indicator 1","Indicator 2","Indicator 2",
                            "Indicator 3","Indicator 3","Indicator 4","Indicator 4"),
              value = c(3, 5, 2.5, 3, 1.3, 2, 4, 4.5,
                        3, 5, 2.5, 3, 1.3, 2, 4, 4.5,
                        3, 5, 2.5, 3, 1.3, 2, 4, 4.5))

shared_df <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(df)

div(

filter_select(
  id = "indicator_selector",
  label = HTML("<span style='font-size: 15px;'>Select Indicator</span>"),
  sharedData = shared_df,
  group = ~ Indicator,
  multiple = F
), 

br(),


plotly::ggplotly(tooltip = c("text"),
ggplot(data = shared_df, 
       aes(x = Group, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Group, alpha = factor(FirstSecond)), position = "dodge", stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.6)) +
  ylim(0,7)+
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                     limits = c(0,7)) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))  +
  labs(x = "\nGroup") +
  guides(fill="none") + 
  ggplot2::theme(
    axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
   panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
    legend.key.height = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
    legend.key.width = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 8),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 5),
    axis.title.x  = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.y  = element_text(size = 12),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 16),
    plot.subtitle  = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.caption = element_text(size =13),
    axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 0.55, size = 10),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10)
  ) ) %>% 
    plotly::config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c(
        "zoom2d","pan2d","select2d","lasso2d",
        "zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d", "autoScale2d",
        "resetScale2d", "hoverClosestCartesian",
        "hoverCompareCartesian", "zoom3d", "pan3d",
        "resetCameraDefault3d", "resetCameraLastSave3d",
        "hoverClosest3d", "orbitRotation", "tableRotation",
        "zoomInGeo", "zoomOutGeo", "resetGeo", "hoverClosestGeo",
        "sendDataToCloud", "hoverClosestGl2d", "hoverClosestPie",
        "toggleHover", "resetViews", "toggleSpikelines", "resetViewMapbox"
      ),
      displayLogo = F) %>%
  plotly::layout(xaxis = list(title = list(standoff = 10,
                                           font = list(family = "Arial", size = 10)),
                              tickfont = list(family = "Arial", size = 9),
                              tickangle = 12),
                 yaxis = list(title = list(standoff = 20,
                                           text = "Average Score",
                                           font = list(family = "Arial", size = 12),
                                           tickfont = list(size = 12)),
                              tickfont = list(size = 12, family = "Arial"),
                              ticks = "outside", 
                              tickcolor='white', 
                              ticklen=10,
                              range = c(0,7),
                              showline = T
                              ),
                 showlegend = F,
                 hoverlabel = list(font=list(size=8)),
                 
                 autosize = T,
                 height = 350
  )

) %>% browsable()


You'll see the plot, each group has a first and second value per indicator. When an indicator is selected, the values being selected are correct (a bar of alpha 1 and alpha 0.6).
In an ideal world, these bars would be next to each other and fill the entire space of the group when the indicator is selected. If I were to re-arrange the df so that the indicator pairs were next to each other, they would be next to each other but still would not fill the entire space for the group.
Would be interested if anyone knows of a way around this!

There are a few things you can do, but I'm not sure what would be most satisfactory - if you take the call alpha = factor(FirstSecond) out of the gglot call you'll see that the bars are then grouped by Group (and see that currently they are grouped/separated by Group and FirstSecond). Is that the "next to each other" you would like to see or would it be better if there was literally no space between bars? Would you want the entire graph size to change then? Or would you want the bars to change size then (e.g., get fatter)?

Hi Kat, so I should have made this clearer in the context. The most important part of the ggplot2 (at least in this context) is the alpha, which I've intentionally put in to apply the shading effect you see for the selections. You see how the "First" is of darker shade and then "Second" is lighter shade, like a before/after effect. Removing the alpha works in moving the bars together, but the shading effect is lost. Does this make sense? Thank you so much for your help!

I wasn't implying that you should drop the alpha to achieve bar consolidation in the graph–I was only trying to explain what was happening. What would you like to see if you could have your ideal graph? What would that look like to you? Can you add an example of what you would like one or two of the graphs to look like in their ideal state? Do you want the physical graph size to be consistent, and the bars to be wider? Bars-same-sized, but centered in the graph and touching?
